# Tkinter sorting grid elements alpabetically

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I'm working on a desktop widget that tracks my investment portfolio.
[How Tkinter portfolio widget looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz1Np.png)

Currently my investments are sorted in two mega-columns (2 megacolumns, each 4 columns wide) in such way that daily best performer is at top left part of a grid and the worst performer is at bottom right.

I want to be able to click on the labels and produce 'excel-like' sorting. Say I click on a "TICKER" label and my feed is sorted alphabetically or I click on "P/L" and my feed is sorted in asc/desc in terms of total investment.

I'm using a grid representation and this is how a chunk of my code looks like

```py
                    ticker_label = Label(root,text=ticker)
                    quote_label = Label(root,text="+"+'{:.2f}'.format(quote))
                    portfolio_allocation_label = Label(root, text=invest)
                    pl_label = Label(root, text=pl)
                    ticker_label.grid(row=separator_1,column=0)
                    quote_label.grid(row=separator_1,column=1)
                    portfolio_allocation_label.grid(row=separator_1, column=2)
                    pl_label.grid(row=separator_1, column=3)
```

How do I sort grid elements in Tkinter alpabetically/numerically from inside the GUI?

I don't necessarilly need the code snippet but a general sense of direction, although snippets are much appreciated as well!

Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: Make your labels in the first row into buttons, write a function that will switch the rows of your labels down under in the order you like. Or use a binding on button-1 on a label, whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Here I get the slaves of a specefied grid which is the labelframe.
- I store the slaves iterate over it and save them in a dict and the values in a list.
- I sort the list and place them by their index

```
import tkinter as tk
from collections import defaultdict

def alpha():
    #get data
    list_of_labels = labelframe.grid_slaves(column=0)
    label_values=[]
    data=defaultdict(list)
    for idx,_ in enumerate(list_of_labels):
        label=labelframe.grid_slaves(row=idx,column=0)[0]
        data[label].append(label['text'])
        label_values.append(label['text'])
    #use data
    sort=sorted(label_values,key=str.lower)
    for idx,value in enumerate(sort):
        for label, v in data.items():
            if v[0] == value:
                label.grid(row=idx, column=0)

root = tk.Tk()

buttonframe = tk.Frame(root)
buttonframe.pack()

button=tk.Button(buttonframe, text='alpha',command=alpha)
button.grid(column=0, row=0)

labelframe= tk.Frame(root)
labelframe.pack()

a = tk.Label(labelframe, text='a')
b = tk.Label(labelframe, text='b')
a.grid(column=0, row=1)
b.grid(column=0, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

If there are questions left, let me know.

Comment: thanks for the idea! i like how you did it, so im going to make a few sorting functions and map the to the buttons

Comment: Its just an exampel. I used defaultdict not known if you need it while I dont know your data structure. You can optimize it for sure, but the principle is clear and the methods what are needed are in this code. May I should annouce that I get the key if the dict by the value. Have fun!